# error : else without if . But i have placed it immediately after it

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

When i execute the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function UploadMessage() {
<%! String message = null; 
    boolean AttemptToUploadFile = false;
%>
    <% 
        message = (String)request.getAttribute("SuccessMessage");
        if(message != null) {
    %>
            alert("File Successfully Uploaded !");
            <% } %>
            <% else if((Boolean)request.getAttribute("UploadAttempt")) { %>
                  alert("Unable to upload file");
                <%}%>

}
```

I get the following error :

```
media/work documents/UnderTest/NetbeansCurrent/ProjectSnippets/build/generated/src/org/apache/jsp/portfolio_005fone_jsp.java:252: error: 'else' without 'if'
else if((Boolean)request.getAttribute("UploadAttempt")) { 
1 error
```

The error says `if` without `else` but i have placed `else` immediately after `if`. Then why the error?

Answer (score 6):

You have to put them in the same script block. Just remove the ending `%>` and the beginning `<%`:

```
<% }
     else if (...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in these two lines:

```
<% } %>
<% else if((Boolean)request.getAttribute("UploadAttempt")) { %>
```

In the resulting java code, they will (basically) be translated to:

```
}
out.append("\n");
else if(...
```

So you need to place the closing parentheses in the same scriptlet like this:

```
<% } else if((Boolean)request.getAttribute("UploadAttempt")) { %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't placed it immediatety after `if`. There is `%>` + newline + `<%` between it. JSP must output the newline in the generated code, so there is something like `out.print("\n\t\t");` (including indention) between `}` and `else if` in the resulting java code.