# Error: 'else' without 'if' in JSP

Tags: jsp

When i'm trying to execute this code, i'm getting this error :  'else' without 'if' .. .... Unable to figure out the error !

```
<% for(int i =1; i<=10 ; i++) {  %>

    <tr>

     <% for(int j=1; j<=10 ; j++) {   %>

        <%  for(int k=0 ; k< un.size() ; k++)  {  

            xax = cp.get(k)/10;
            yax = cp.get(k)%10;
            co = col.get(k)+".jpg";
        %>


        <%   if(xax==i && yax ==j) { %>   <td> <img src=<%=co%> id="pawn">  </td> <%  j++;} %> 

        <%   else { %> <td>  </td>  <% j++; }  %>


     <% } %>
     <% } %>



        </tr>

   <% } %>
```

Comment: This code is quite problematic & hard to debug. Very fragmented (you can combine the code blocks) & used 3 nested for-loop. Performance could be a problem and

Comment: Anyhow you are using j++ in both if and else and your else has only that statement. Why don't you remove else from your code and write the j++ after if block.

Comment: @prudhvi  I'm trying to get a 10x10 table snakes and ladder table. if i remove else, empty columns will not get printed on the page.

Comment: I see, you have <td></td> also.

Comment: This question might be duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310871/error-else-without-if-but-i-have-placed-it-immediately-after-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
  <%   if(xax==i && yax ==j) { %> 
  <td> <img src=<%=co%> id="pawn">  </td> 
<%  j++;}  else { %> 
<td>  </td> 


 <% j++; }  %>
```

Hope it will help.!!